# Three different HEX having same wallet address how possible?

Tags: private-key, hash, address-generation, p2sh, p2wpkh

HEX1:

1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111

```
public key:

044f355bdcb7cc0af728ef3cceb9615d90684bb5b2ca5f859ab0f0b704075871aa385b6b1b8ead809ca67454d9683fcf2ba03456d6fe2c4abe2b07f0fbdbb2f1c1                                

Wallet Uncompressed:
                                    1MsHWS1BnwMc3tLE8G35UXsS58fKipzB7a

private key Wif:

5HwoXVkHoRM8sL2KmNRS217n1g8mPPBomrY7yehCuXC1115WWsh

public key compressed:

b'\x03O5[\xdc\xb7\xcc\n\xf7(\xef<\xce\xb9a]\x90hK\xb5\xb2\xca_\x85\x9a\xb0\xf0\xb7\x04\x07Xq\xaa'

Wallet Compressed:

1Q1pE5vPGEEMqRcVRMbtBK842Y6Pzo6nK9
```

HEX 2:
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111101

```
public key:

034f355bdcb7cc0af728ef3cceb9615d90684bb5b2ca5f859ab0f0b704075871aa          
                               
Wallet Uncompressed:              
                                 1Q1pE5vPGEEMqRcVRMbtBK842Y6Pzo6nK9

Private key wif:

5HwoXVkHoRM8sL2KmNRS217n1g8mPPBomrY7yehCuXC1115WWsh

public key comp:

b'\x03O5[\xdc\xb7\xcc\n\xf7(\xef<\xce\xb9a]\x90hK\xb5\xb2\xca_\x85\x9a\xb0\xf0\xb7\x04\x07Xq\xaa'

Wallet compressed:

1Q1pE5vPGEEMqRcVRMbtBK842Y6Pzo6nK9
```

HEX 3:

111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100

```
Public key:

034f355bdcb7cc0af728ef3cceb9615d90684bb5b2ca5f859ab0f0b704075871aa                                          

Wallet Uncompressed:                      

1Q1pE5vPGEEMqRcVRMbtBK842Y6Pzo6nK9


priv compressed:

5HwoXVkHoRM8sL2KmNRS217n1g8mPPBomrY7yehCuXC1115WWsh

public key compressed:

b'\x03O5[\xdc\xb7\xcc\n\xf7(\xef<\xce\xb9a]\x90hK\xb5\xb2\xca_\x85\x9a\xb0\xf0\xb7\x04\x07Xq\xaa'

Wallet compressed:

1Q1pE5vPGEEMqRcVRMbtBK842Y6Pzo6nK9
```

Pls i want to know how possible for the different hash to have same wallet.

NOTE: I am using bitcoin python library to generate the wallets
Only the first hash is valid on bitaddress.org when checked for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Screenshot of the three hex representations in an editor]

Private keys are 256-bit numbers. The first "HEX" you list has 64 characters, which corresponds to 256 bit, while the other two have 66 characters. Since all three share the same first 64 characters, I surmise that the library you're using simply drops the additional data beyond the first 256 bit.

Comment: All three hex are 64 characters, just a change at the ending from 1 to 0.

Comment: My text editor begs to differ.

Comment: If it is more or less than 64 characters the bitcoin library will trow an exception and besides i have recounted.

Comment: I just copied what you posted in your question. If you are working with something else, please edit your question.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake i have confirmed and you are right.